# A collection of stories about Buddha past lives

Tags: reference-request, buddha, life, jataka

Where can i find the collection of these stories about Buddha past lives? Any book or video about this stories especially stream-enterer in series or probably some before this stage.

One life before i found was a king.

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(Buddhism))

Comment: Should be in the Jataka: https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/minor/kn/ja

Answer (score 1):

Please see [The Jataka or Stories of the Buddha's Former Births](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/j1/index.htm) (at sacred-texts.com), translated by various persons under the editorship of E.B. Cowell.

This translation comes in six volumes and was published between 1895 and 1907.

The introduction states:

> The Jataka is a massive collection of Buddhist folklore about previous
> incarnations of the Buddha, both in human and animal form. Originally
> written in Pali, and dating to at least 380 BCE, the Jataka includes
> many stories which have traveled afar. Many of these can be traced
> cross-culturally in the folklore of many countries.

The Jataka is part of the Khuddaka Nikaya (minor collection) of the Sutta Pitaka (the basket of discourses) of the [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81li_Canon).